# how to make one string from several? Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, recursion, stack

I make some method, that takes digits and operands from stack and display it in a more user friendly style. The problem is with descriptionString variable, it return null in part when topOfStack is "+". I show a log below.

```
+(NSString *)descriptionOfTopOfStack:(NSMutableArray *)stack
{

    NSString *descriptionString;
    id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
    NSString *secondInStack;
    NSString *thirdInStack;
    if (topOfStack)
    [stack removeLastObject];    
    if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        descriptionString = [topOfStack stringValue];
    }
    else if([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        if(([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"+"]) || ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"—"])){
            secondInStack = [self descriptionOfTopOfStack:stack];
            thirdInStack = [self descriptionOfTopOfStack:stack];
           descriptionString = [descriptionString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",thirdInStack,topOfStack,secondInStack]; 
          NSLog(@"description is %@",descriptionString);

        }

    }
    return descriptionString;
}
```

i made example with 2 + 6, this is log:

- 2012-02-21 22:09:39.983 Calculator[12536:f803]  stack = (
  2,
  6,
  "+"
  )
- 2012-02-21 22:09:39.983 Calculator[12536:f803] description is (null)

Why descriptionString is null? Where i made a mistake? Thanks

Comment: This is a classic computer science homework assignment....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
descriptionString = [descriptionString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",thirdInStack,topOfStack,secondInStack];
```

The variable `descriptionString` is `nil`. Replace that line with the following.

```
descriptionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",thirdInStack,topOfStack,secondInStack];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not setting a value to the `descriptionString` variable in the other branch of the `if`, so you are appending string to `null`. You could set the variable, or you could use `[NSString stringWithFormat:format]`:

```
if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    descriptionString = [topOfStack stringValue];
}
else if([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
    if(([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"+"]) || ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"—"])){
        secondInStack = [self descriptionOfTopOfStack:stack];
        thirdInStack = [self descriptionOfTopOfStack:stack];
       descriptionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",thirdInStack,topOfStack,secondInStack]; 
      NSLog(@"description is %@",descriptionString);

    }

}
```